# Tag search with accented characters should de-accent them, rather than delete them

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

If you create a new tag with an accented character, it gets converted to an un-accented character. For instance:

> *pokémon* → [pokemon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon)

But when you search through this site's search box, the accented character is deleted. So when you search for `[pokémon]` in the search box, it is converted to `[pokmon]`. There should be consistency with this.

There was [a feature request for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135142/191265) in Meta Stack Exchange, and it was marked as "status-complete" in 2012 and indeed it looks like it's working fine on that site. A mod noted that it would be rolled out in the next version. I'm not sure if it never made its way to Gaming Stack Exchange, but I see no reason that this shouldn't be intended behavior for our site.

Comment: Are you sure that the tag change is automatic for accented characters and not just a manually created tag synonym for the pokemon games?

Comment: Interestingly, the example case in that feature request doesn't seem to work anymore network-wide, so if anything this is likely a bug